# Java read complex xml file without schema to pojo

Tags: java, xml, pojo

I need to parse a really big and deeply nested xml file into a tree of pojos.
Unfortunately there is no xml schema because the format is too old.
*(For the curious ones here is a [link](http://wiki.swimrankings.net/index.php/swimrankings:Lenex) to the specification)*
I already made the pojos according to the specification and even annotated all of the fields with `@Nonnull` and `@Nullable`.

Now how do I read the xml file and map the values and attributes, without creating a constructor in each java object that explicitly assigns the the attributes to the class members and constructs the xml tree recursively?

Comment: I would take the time to write an XML schema for it.  It's not terribly long, and if you make it available to the public, you may extend the life of the Lenex format.

Comment: @VGR Apparently JAXB is able to automatically create such a schema. I might look into it. Can I assume you are familiar with the LENEX format?

Comment: "Familiar" would be giving me far too much credit.  I read the documentation to which you linked, from start to end.

Comment: @VGR It's quite complex. I still don't see what is linked with what, even though I copied the whole file into java classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding)) will do the Job for you. 
Essentially, this allows you to store POJOs as XML and vice-versa, by creating the classes and adding annotations to them.

Here is a simple tutorial on how to use this: 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Best wishes

Comment: Thank you. I thought JAXB was only usable if there is already a XML schema. Apparently not.. all the better.